# Syntastic only runs in certain directories

Tags: python, vim, conda, syntastic

I've got `vim` (`8.0.1150`) installed with `syntastic` (re-installed today), and I'm using `conda` to manage my environments, on a Mac running Sierra.

When I'm at the top-level of a repo I'm working on, if I open vim:

```
$ vim src/python/some/fun/file.py
```

then syntastic works as expected, highlighting errors.

However, if I move further down this chain, e.g.:

```
$ cd src/python/some
$ vim fun/file.py
```

all of a sudden, syntastic no longer displays any errors.

Since I haven't changed `conda` environments, and since `vim` is just `/usr/local/bin/vim`, I can't figure out what's changing from one opening to the next that would cause this difference in output.

Happy to provide any further system details, I just don't know which ones are relevant.

Comment: Open your test file, set `g:syntastic_debug` to 3, run `:SyntasticCheck`, run `:mes`, and read the output.  If you can't figure out what's wrong feel free to post that output to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues).

Comment: @lcd047 - I'll give that a whirl and follow up either way. Thanks!

Comment: @lcd047 - found it! Turns out this code base has lots of filename clashes with other packages. So `flake8` wouldn't run because it was importing the local `email` package rather than the actual python one. Different errors from different directories amount to the same reasoning. Guess I'll have to tweak my `PYTHONPATH` a little more to get this working. Thanks for sending me in the right direction!